# Finding dependecies between modules of a legacy ANT project for migration to IVY

Tags: ant, ivy, dependency-management

I am dealing with a project using using ANT to build the source code into a EAR. The project over couple of years has grown to a mammoth size, more than fifty modules, and not surprisingly it takes 2 hours to build the source code.

The obvious decision that I made was to migrate this to a modular build using IVY for dependency management between sub-modules of the EAR, so I build only the modules that have changed and then package a new EAR every time. I am stuck trying to find out a good way of figuring out dependencies between these sub-modules. Note that 3rd party dependencies were easy to crack. I simply move all that is in the lib folder of these sub-modules to IVY. But, the former is where I am stuck. 
This is what they do:

1. Copy source from all modules to a directory
2. Compile "everything" into a global.jar
3. Add this global.jar to the classpath
4. Build every individual module thereafter

Now how do I figure out that for example Module C depends on module A and B and so A and B should go as ivy dependency in the former? One way could be to add one module at a time in eclipse and try building, and then eleminate failures because of missing classes; but there has to be a better way than this, I cannot imagine spending the next one month of life figuring that out :)

Comment: Do you want to set dependencies between modules using ivy? You can read more here http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html.

Comment: Yes that is the end goal; problem here is to find those dependencies so I can define them in IVY file; and given the current build method above; there is not straight forward way that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create ivy repository. I don't know how to do it. Try to find it on ivy site. After that you need to create `build.xml` and `ivy.xml` file.

Example build.xml which builds some product which depends on `module1`

```
<project name="ivy.test" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <!-- this line tells ivy to use ${ivy.settings.file} where are ivy repositories; more info http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings.html -->
        <ivy:configure file="${ivy.settings.file}"/>
        <!-- resolve ivy dependencies from ivy.xml and put them in ivy cache dir -->
        <ivy:resolve file="${build.dir}/ivy.xml" transitive="false" />
        <!-- finally copy resolved dependencies to ${ivy.lib.dir} -->
        <ivy:retrieve conf="default" pattern="${ivy.lib.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Example ivy.xml used to resolve dependencies (will try to find `module1` in one of ivy repository defined in ivysettings file)

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="your.organisation" module="modulename">
        <ivyauthor name="yourname" />
    </info>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" description="default conf" />
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency name="module1" org="your.organisation" rev="latest.release" conf="default->default" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Example ivy.xml used by `module1` project (this project depends on `module2` and `module3`; `module1` is also published in repository)

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="your.organisation" module="module1"> <!-- module name is used in dependency -->
        <ivyauthor name="yourname"/>
    </info>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" description="default configuration"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="module" ext="dll" type="dll" conf="default"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency name="module2" org="your.organisation" rev="latest.release" conf="default->default" />
        <dependency name="module3" org="your.organisation" rev="latest.release" conf="default->default" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: I might have not been able to express the question properly but my problem is not with Ivy syntax. my problem is about finding out the dependency structure that goes into the ivy file. If I take your reply; I have to find out that module2 and 3 are dependencies of module1.

Comment: Where do you want to use this `dependency structure` information? In build.xml or outside of it?

Comment: In the build.xml ofcourse, my problem is that because everything is copied to a single source directory and single global.jar is made out of it, I am stuck figuring out this dependency structure before I could use it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what do you want to do. If you want to download dependencies transitive you can use `transitive` argument (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html). If you want to get some information from ivy.xml you can use ivy ant tasks (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/ant.html). For example `listmodules` will list repo modules matching some criteria.

Comment: Never Mind :). Wrote a script that goes through eclipse settings of each module to find out other eclipse projects it depends on. I have the info that I wanted now.